# Problem with assigning object for key value

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to initialize some values using in my interface using a dictionary.
This are the values that the dictionary has:

```
{
  "d":[],
  "tH":123456789213,
  "e":NO,
  "a":"on"
}
```

To initialize I use the following method:

```
- (id)initWithDict:(NSDictionary *)dict{

    self = [super initWithDict: dict];
    self.targetHour = [dict objectForKey:@"tH"];
    self.action = [dict objectForKey:@"a"];
    self.days = [dict objectForKey:@"d"];
    self.enabled = [dict objectForKey:@"e"];


    if(!dict[@"id"]){

        self.id = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    }

    return self;
}
```

No all the values are correct except `self.enabled` which for some reason is assigned to `YES` instead of `NO`. I can't figure out what's wrong and why it keeps getting the incorrect value.

Comment: You have key `th` in the dictionary but `objectForKey:@"tH"` in your code. I’m betting this is not your real dictionary. Show real code / values please.

Comment: it's a typo here. thanks.

Comment: You should not be typing code in SO. Copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NO` is defined as 0 (though in modern systems it gets there via `__objc_no`, that's still 0 in this context). You can't put that in a NSDictionary. If you did, it would be the same as `nil` and act as removing the key.

I suspect this is actually `@NO`, which is the NSNumber version of the value, and is an object (so can be put in an NSDictionary). (I suspect this because you also have `[]` in your dictionary, which is also an impossible value in an `NSDictionary`. Since NO is also invalid JSON, I don't think you're showing us the real data.)

If `self.enabled` is a BOOL, then when you fetch `objectForKey:` that will return an object and try to assign the value to the BOOL. The object likely is a tagged pointer, but its overall value is likely non-zero. Non-zero values are true.

I would expect a warning in this case, however. Have you resolved all warnings in this project?